# Reducing Redundancy with NodeJS and Cheerio

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I was just wondering how I would reduce redundancy in these two web scrapers, since I don't want it to request the website twice. I'm new to this and not very familiar with the syntax. Here's the snippet of code:

```
            request(website_url, function(err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.title').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).children('h2').children('span').text();
                titles.push(title);
            });

        request(website_url, function(err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.post-box-excerpt').each(function(){
                var caption = $(this).children('p').text();
                captions.push(caption);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use make one single call to the api:

```
request(website_url, function (err, resp, body) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('.title').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).children('h2').children('span').text();
    titles.push(title);
  });

  $('.post-box-excerpt').each(function () {
    var caption = $(this).children('p').text();
    captions.push(caption);
  });
});
```